# Tree menu in Symfony 2, in one entity

Tags: symfony, entity, relation

I'm using Symfony 2.3 framework.

I am trying to create a system that will allow me to easily create tree menu (with root and child).

This field allows to show whether it is a root or child (id of this entity another record).

Now I want to do something like relation OneToMany but I don't know how. It is possibility to create relation with this same entity?

I thing about create method 'getChildren' in this entity but I don't know what operation I should to do.

Example:

### class site { private $id; private $name; private $parent; }

and records in db:
1 category_1 0
2 subcategory_1 1
3 subcategory_2 1
etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is even an example in the doctrine documentation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

But if you really want to build a Tree you could also consider the TreeExtension which uses a slightly different database model, which is a little bit more performant:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md